# proguard: Unable to disable obfuscation to one specific class

Tags: android, proguard, android-obfuscation

I have the following for debug purposes:

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

I have a class MyClass, and I'm using Gson to convert it to JSON before sending it to my server. While I expect the JSON to be `{"name":"blah", "age": 40}`, the server receives it as `{"a":"blah", "b": 40}`. I tried several things in the proguard rule files but to no avail. Here is an example of my latest try:

> -keep public class com.package.package.MyClass  { *; }

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: add the `SerializedName` annotation to the fields, and add `-keepattributes *Annotation*` to your proguard config. This will obfuscate the class, but keep it's serialization names

Comment: I read about it but didn't try it because I understood that the keep class way is more recommended. If nothing else works, I will try it. My question is what's wrong with what I did. Thanks.

Comment: you may also try `-keepclassmembers` of your class

Comment: Will try it, is the syntax the same? meaning -keepclassmembers com.package.package.MyClass { *; }?

Comment: I can't remember for sure, but I think yes

Comment: well, nothing worked, I used the SerializedName

Comment: did the SerializedName work?

Comment: yes it did. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried serialization annotation

```
@SerializedName("name")
String name ="";
```

Comment: See my comment above